# unity3d write csv file php

Tags: php, unity-game-engine

hope someone can help me. I made a unity3d game for webplayer. Now i need to store some data e.g. the time how long someone has played the game in a csv file. 
Does anyone know how i can test if my php and javascript for writing to this csv file 
in my javascript i habe this line

```
var postDataURL = "myurl/data.php?";
```

but i don't have a url til now so i need to test this locally and i don't know what to add for the url i always get this error:
Could not resolve host: C; No data record of requested type
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set up a web server to run locally. At that point you can target your form submission at http:// localhost/data.php and things will work perfectly. Apache is really easy to set up but you might want to look into something like WAMP (Windows Apache MySql PHP.)

http://www.wampserver.com/en/

Answer (score 0):

First of all in order to access your PHP script to either send or retrieve information You need to use the WWW class with your url.

Next is there a reason that you want to write it to a csv file. If your just trying to store information that is pervasive across all session runs you can write data to player prefs.

```
PlayerPrefs.SetString("KeyName", Value);
```

Retrieve the data at any time using

```
PlayerPrefs.GetString("KeyName")
```

This is good for keeping high scores and such

Finally to directly answer your question my favorite is installing apache because it sets up in minutes with out havnt to know what your doing

http://httpd.apache.org/

after install find your web root and place the file in there. You can access the file using `http://localhost/yourPHPfile.php`

Make sure you install php on your machine as well.